# How is a C++ program loaded into memory

Tags: c++

If i static compile an executable prog.exe with static.lib
When prog.exe is run, will it load all the binary for prog.exe which includes static.lib?

When prog.exe is first loaded, for static and global variables is the memory on RAM used?

The memory allocation of address occurring at compile time and at run time, these memory addresses are occupied?

Are the same virtual addresses mapped to different physical memory addresses?

I have heard infrequent accessed variables will not be present in RAM but hard disk, how is this information of infrequent accessed variables stored, is it stored in the prog.exe that Var1 is not frequently accessed and should be stored in hard disk?

When it is required, it is loaded from hard disk?

Comment: Depends on executable format. For ELF see https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/

Comment: It is not related to the programming language and is operating system dependent. But in general separate variables don’t exist and aren’t put on disk if infrequently used. Memory blocks may get paged out if out of memory and not used, but that’s another thing and not related to variables.

Answer (score 1):

In general, executables are memory mapped, similar to how you can map a "normal" data file. When the process tries to access a mapped page which is not yet present in memory, it traps into the OS which takes care of reading the data from disk and places it in RAM.

For static variables, the program loader takes care of allocating them before calling main().

Answer (score 0):

> If i static compile an executable prog.exe with static.lib When prog.exe is run, will it load all the binary for prog.exe which includes static.lib?

Programs can be partially loaded into RAM. It is the operating system's job to load a part of the program on demand. The mechanism for that is [page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault)

> When prog.exe is first loaded, for static and global variables is the memory on RAM used?

Yes

> The memory allocation of address occurring at compile time and at run time, these memory addresses are occupied?

The operating system can not generally know how much memory a process will need.

> Are the same virtual addresses mapped to different physical memory addresses?

Yes, this concept is called [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

> I have heard infrequent accessed variables will not be present in RAM but hard disk, how is this information of infrequent accessed variables stored, is it stored in the prog.exe that Var1 is not frequently accessed and should be stored in hard disk?

I don't think any operating system does this. It would be very inefficient. A similar thing is [swap partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Unix_and_Unix-like_systems)

Comment: But if there are multiple programs, how can they all be loaded into main memory RAM, some of their programs must reside in HDD? How is it decided which parts of the program reside in the HDD? Or is each program loaded partially till the end of the program?

Comment: HDD is for non-volatile storage. A program is in HDD. It is also loaded into RAM (at least partially) before running. There can be hundreds or thousands of programs running at the same time and they can all be loaded into RAM. The OS decides what part of the program to load and when.